# Edit SVG in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svg

I want to edit SVG files in Eclipse. I don't know why it doesn't work, but Eclipse opens Sublime when I double click an SVG file. I tried to install the Docfacto plugin, but Eclipse stalls when I open or create an SVG file.

I remember that elsewhere it has worked. I don't need a graphical editor, just something compareble to XML or HTML, so with color coding and maybe matching tags.

**How can I open and edit SVG files in Eclipse?**

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Window->Preferences
2. Select General->Editors->File Associations
3. Look for *.svg in the top list.

You should be able to modify the default editor(s) in the bottom pane.  Mine is set to "XML Editor".

[image]

Comment: When I do this I can open SVG documents in Eclipse, but I don't see color coding.

Comment: Do you have the Eclipse Web Tools extension installed?  There is an XML editor as part of that which does syntax highlighting.

Comment: XML is color coded, HTML and other languages as well. SVG documents - with .svg file extension, XML declaration and SVG namespace in it - are not color coded.

Comment: I added a screenshot for comparison.

Comment: In Eclipse Neon (XML Editors and Tools 3.8.2.v20170227044) I can open svg with the XML editor, and it is color coded, but it won't format/pretty print nicely for me (unlike other XML files) and changing the extension to .xml doesn't help.  Its not putting opening tags on a new line (nor indenting them).  And there is nothing in preferences I can see which affects this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a little tricky if you don't know: 
first define **svg** as an **xml content type**:

1. Preferences > General > Content Types
2. Select `XML` in the upper right box
3. Click the `Add...` button next to the bottom right box
4. Add `*.svg` and click OK

---

Then do what @Paul LeBeau proposed:

1. Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations
2. Select `*.svg` or `add it` if it is not yet in the list
3. Mark `XML Editor` as `default` in the bottom box
4. `Apply and Close`

---

Finally open a **fresh svg file** to test the default file association, if you open the same file as before eclipse will remember the previous (text) editor and you will see no syntax colouring. Or right click on a file and choose `Open With` > `XML Editor` to test if the colour coding works.